# Big problem when trying to yarn build or yarn start on a react app client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, build

I'm trying to build a react app but it's not working anymore and I really have no clue how it happened! I really need you help please!
Here is the error I have in the terminal after an attempt on a yarn build:

```
/var/www/html/Portfolio/server/client $ yarn build
yarn run v1.12.1
warning package.json: No license field
warning Skipping preferred cache folder "/home/mint/.cache/yarn" because it is not writable.
warning Selected the next writable cache folder in the list, will be "/tmp/.yarn-cache-999".
$ node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js
Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options[0] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:
   [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, toType?, force?, flatten?, transform?, cacheTransform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
    at validate (/var/www/html/Portfolio/server/client/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:96:11)
    at new CopyPlugin (/var/www/html/Portfolio/server/client/node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:24:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/Portfolio/server/client/config/webpack.common.js:22:5)
    at Module._compile (/var/www/html/Portfolio/server/client/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (/var/www/html/Portfolio/server/client/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/Portfolio/server/client/config/webpack.prod.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (/var/www/html/Portfolio/server/client/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (/var/www/html/Portfolio/server/client/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Looks like your `config/webpack.prod.js` file is missing a `patterns` option, could you copy the contents of that file here to help?

Comment: corrected it with this : npm install --save copy-webpack-plugin@5.1.1

Comment: @LukeStorry sorry didn't see your response ! well i probably still have a problem with webpack, the solution i found wasn't enought i have another issue with it, dunno if i shold talk about it here or create a new issue :/